# Laplace transform of this problem

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm a bit confused in finding the laplace transform of the following:

$f(t) = e^{2t} u(t) $

I know how to solve it if it we're only $e^{2t}$ but the $u(t)$ is confusing.

Comment: It changes nothing. The u(t) simply restricts f(t) to values of t greater than or equal to 0. Since the transform is defined for t greater than or equal to 0 anyway the multiplication by u(t) has no effect on the transform value.

Comment: @Paul Thanks, that's what I assumed as well. It's just figuring out the Laplace transform of $e^{2t}$ that I need to work out. The u(t) was a new notation for me.

Comment: @Paul : no don't say that... forget about the $\int_0^\infty$ Laplace transform, always consider instead the bilateral Laplace transform of $f(t) = \ldots u(t)$